# How can I unbold the volumn number in Overleaf (natbib, APA style)?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using natbib package, and the apa sytle (\bibliographystyle{dcu}). But in the reference list, the volumn number is bold. How can I make it unbold? I saw some methods that modify some documents, but I am using Overleaf. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the boldface instruction is hardwired in `dcu.bst`.

You can find `dcu.bst` in your TeX system and copy it in a file called `dcu-mod.bst` in the same directory as your main file.

Now edit the new file so that the line

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume embolden field.or.null
  number empty$
```

to

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
```

(only the middle line needs editing, I left the surrounding ones for context).

Now change the `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` declaration into

```
\bibliographystyle{dcu-mod}
```

rerun LaTeX, BibTeX and LaTeX again.

**Example**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={20},
  year={2022},
  pages={1-1},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{dcu-mod}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!